# How to specify Bootstrap columns for Autoform fields?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor-autoform

I'd like to have some of my afQuickFields in columns (i.e. side-by-side).

This does not work:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{> afQuickField name='title'}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{> afQuickField name='subtitle'}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I made a mistake elsewhere - had the wrong template name!

My original solution does work.